# Running python script through crontab can't find imports

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to run a python script through crontab, but it can't import any of the libraries that it needs when it is run this way. When I run the scripts outside of crontab, there is no issue, and I know that I have these libraries installed.

Do I need to specify a path to them or something?

Many thanks

crontab file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=jess.chambers@gmail.com
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local
*/1 * * * * cd ~/Downloads/guichets && python newRdvChecker.py -G1 -S0 >>/tmp/stdout.log 2>&1
*/1 * * * * cd ~/Downloads/guichets && python newRdvChecker.py -G2 -S20 >>/tmp/stdout.log 2>&1
*/1 * * * * cd ~/Downloads/guichets && python newRdvChecker.py -G3 -S40  >>/tmp/stdout.log 2>&1
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newRdvChecker.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
```

I'm running this setup on my Linux Mint computer, if that makes a difference

Comment: do you use virtualenv?

Comment: @BearBrown No.. not knowingly at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine what exact python executable you use when running the script from CLI (with `which python`) and specify the full path to python in your crontab.

Comment: so "*/1 * * * * cd ~/Downloads/guichets && python newRdvChecker.py -G3 -S40" becomes "*/1 * * * * cd ~/Downloads/guichets && path/to/python newRdvChecker.py -G3 -S40"?